# Bluetooth com port java

Tags: java, bluetooth, rxtx

Eсть **BT** на устройстве и есть **BT** на компьютере. Хочу реализовать программу на java, которая подключается к **BT** и отправляет данные на устройство.

Сделал пока через библиотеку **RXTXComm**. К порту `COM3` подключается, данные отправляются, а вот к `COM6` (на этом порту находится Bluetooth serial port) не подключается и данные не отправляются.

Как сделать, чтобы программа подключалась в Bluetooth com port?

Comment: Что значит "не подключается"? Какую ошибку выдаёт, что пишет? Какой конкретный код работает с одним портом, не работает с другим? Есть ли примеры программ (возможно, сторонних), которые у вас корректно работают с `COM6`, почему вы уверены, что проблема именно в Java-коде?